# UDP sender & receiver at the same time C

Tags: c, udp, broadcast

I have to write a C app that will act as both UDP sender & receiver. The program should first detect the broadcast address, then send the message JOIN  (name is read), 1 time/minute, then some messages. I understood the part with broadcasting packages. I can't figure out how to turn my sender into a receiver also.
  My code so far:
---old code ---

Edit:
  I now know that I have solve this without select() or poll(), but with fork()..Something like creating 2 separate processes that will deal with writing to the socket and, respectively, reading data from the socket. I manage to send data. I have some troubles reading data from the socket. I receive smth like the last characters of the string I send. Also, I have an error ":Invalid argument"..I've tried debugging but I don't really know where this error comes from. It appears just after I do the fork(). I have to be able to ignore mssages that I send somehow, but testing this locally it's confusing (I have to receive messages from others and also, know the IP address that sent me the message). Now, if I start the app twice, In one app I don't receive messages from the other, just the last characters of what the app sends. 
Here's my code:

```
#includes..
#define MAXLEN 100
#define MAXNAME 20
#define PORT 8888
#define MAX 20

int sockfd;
struct sockaddr_in socket_in;   //connector's info
char name[MAXNAME];
int numbytes;
 char senders[MAX];

void sendJoin (int signal) {
    if ((numbytes=sendto(sockfd, name, strlen(name), 0,
             (struct sockaddr *)&socket_in, sizeof(socket_in))) == -1) {
        perror("sendto");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Sent %s to %s (%d bytes)\n", name,inet_ntoa(socket_in.sin_addr),numbytes);
    alarm(5);
}

void leaveGroup(int signal) {
    /* Broadcast LEAVE and end execution */
    char msg[10];
    strcpy(msg, "LEAVE\0");
    if ((numbytes=sendto(sockfd, msg, strlen(msg), 0,
             (struct sockaddr *)&socket_in, sizeof(socket_in))) == -1) {
        perror("sendLEAVE");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("\nSent LEAVE message to %s (%d bytes)\n",      inet_ntoa(socket_in.sin_addr),numbytes);    
    scanf("%s", msg);
    close(sockfd);
    exit(1);
}

void read_socks() {   
    char message[MAXLEN];
    int size = sizeof(socket_in);
    numbytes = recvfrom (sockfd, &message, 1, 0,
                (struct sockaddr*) &socket_in, &size);
    if(strcmp(message, name)!=0) {
        printf("Received: %s\n", message);
    }
}

int main(void){

struct hostent *hst;   
int broadcast = 1; 

if ((hst=gethostbyname("192.168.240.255")) == NULL) {  // get the host info
    perror("gethostbyname");
    exit(1);
}

if((sockfd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0))==-1) {
    perror("socket");
    exit(1);
}
if(setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &broadcast, sizeof(broadcast))==-1){
    perror("setsockopt(SO_BROADCAST)");
    exit(1);
}

memset(&socket_in, 0, sizeof(socket_in));
socket_in.sin_family = AF_INET;
socket_in.sin_port = htons(PORT);
socket_in.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)hst->h_addr);

signal(SIGINT, leaveGroup);
signal(SIGALRM, sendJoin);

printf("NAME: ");
fgets(name,MAXNAME,stdin);
strcpy(name,strcat("JOIN: ", name));
name[strlen(name)-1]='\0';
if ((numbytes=sendto(sockfd, name, strlen(name), 0,
             (struct sockaddr *)&socket_in, sizeof(socket_in))) == -1) {
        perror("sendto");
        exit(1);
    }

printf("Sent %s to %s (%d bytes)\n", name,inet_ntoa(socket_in.sin_addr),numbytes);      
alarm(5);

while (1)
{        
    int pid = fork();
    if(pid==0){            //Child process reads from the socket
        memset(&socket_in, 0, sizeof(socket_in));
        socket_in.sin_family = AF_INET;
        socket_in.sin_port = htons(PORT);
        socket_in.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)hst->h_addr);
        sockfd = bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &socket_in, sizeof(socket_in));
        if(sockfd==-1) perror("Bind error. Port is already in use!");
        read_socks();
        exit(0);
    }
    else if(pid > 0){    //Parent process sends data through the socket
        memset(&socket_in, 0, sizeof(socket_in));
        socket_in.sin_family = AF_INET;
        socket_in.sin_port = htons(PORT);
        socket_in.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)hst->h_addr);
        if ((numbytes=sendto(sockfd, name, strlen(name), 0,
             (struct sockaddr *)&socket_in, sizeof(socket_in))) == -1) {
            perror("sendto");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    sleep(4);
    }
close(sockfd);
return 0;
}
```

I would greatly appreaciate some suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is suspend your program until one of two things happen:

- somebody sends you a UDP message
- the minute is up (you need to send your broadcast message)

The solution on unix, if you want to suspend until one of multiple things happen, is the function `select()`.

Another possible solution in your case is to use non-blocking I/O and check for new packages once in a while -- but that's basically active polling and active polling is bad, bad, bad.

The problem you face with your code is that your program is blocked in `recvfrom()` until it gets a message. *(Note: I'm not totally sure whether your SIGALRM method should indeed work during blocked I/O wait but I assume the signal gets queued until your reading operation is finished (data received))*

Comment: With signal() as joanna used it, the SIGALRM will not interrupt. If joanna used sigaction() there is a SA_RESTART flag that when set to 0 will make a signal interrupt most system calls.

Answer (score 1):

You need a select or poll loop. There are plenty of StackOverflow questions relating to these.

I also recommend setting your sockets to non-blocking to avoid some rare problems.

Or if you are writing on Windows you can set your networking up to use events.

Answer (score 0):

`select(2)`, `poll(2)` and relatives let you wait for events on file descriptors and timeouts.

When using one of these syscalls, there is no need to use `alarm()`. `alarm()` is sometimes used to launch a `read(2)` or `write(2)` call with a timeout (though I prefer to use `select()` even in this case, it means I don't care who else might be using `SIGALARM`).

Both `poll()` and `select()` return `0` when the timeout expires. Some `select()` implementations update the `timeout` parameter with the remaining time, others don't. In any case, since `select()` or `poll()` may have awakened earlier for processing some other event (or because they were interrupted by a signal), the correct thing to do is checking if the timeout has really expired / recalculating the timeout, something which has traditionally been done using `time(2)` or `gettimeofday(2)`, but which in modern times should be better done using `clock_gettime(2)` with the `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` clock, which is immune to clock adjustments (`date(1)`, leap seconds, daylight saving time, ...).